# Error while testing value.target.value statement in Karma Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, ionic3, angular-test

Please help to resolve the below issue. value is an touched event !

> Err - value is not defined.

Component file:

```
searchElement(value)
{
  let val = value.target.value;
  if (val && val.trim() != '')
  //code snippet
  }
}
```

spec file:

```
it('searchElement',()=> {

  // how to set the "value" which is having target value and pass it to real method as a param.
    let value =  {
//              "target": {
//                 "value": "abc"
//                }
//            };      
//     comp.searchElement(value); 
//     fixture.detectChanges();
//     expect(comp.searchElement).toBeTruthy();     

)};
```

Comment: u should use sinon and stub to mock the functionality of it

Comment: @FadiAboMsalam Is there any option in karma+Jasmine we can test this event and assign the value.When we search this method invoke.